Can Eldritch Blast (with multiple blasts) be used as a Warcaster opportunity attack?
The War Caster feat says:

When a hostile creature's movement provokes an opportunity attack from you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time of 1 action and must target only that creature.

So can a character with War Caster feat cast Eldritch Blast as an opportunity attack provoked by a hostile creature's movement--if they are entitled to multiple eldritch blasts per cast--so long as they only target the creature provoking the OA?

I closed this since it has been already asked before (and my previous search, before providing my answer, did not lead to that post). If you believe that there are some differences from the linked post, please clarify them in order to reopen your question.
